# Where can I ask about setting up a secure network at home

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I am looking to set up some kind of mesh network in my home. I know basic networking and setting up a bridge. But I was thinking I would come here to get some guidance on what kind of network would work best etc. I've got ethernet ports all over my house, so putting access points is an option, but ideally I would really like it to be the same network. The only thing is, I know I am not allowed to ask about home networking questions on here, so I was wondering where might be a good place to ask this kind of question?

Comment: You can have multiple access point all be on the same network. A WAP is a bridge, like a switch, and absent a configuration to the contrary, all the switch ports will be in the same LAN. Any switches that you connect to that switch will be on the same LAN, just like any WAPs you connect.

Answer (score 3):

[Superuser](https://superuser.com) is the right place for home networking questions. Try to avoid questions asking for 'the best way', since they often lead to opinion based answers.